# query doens't fill hashmap

Tags: sql

We made this piece of code, but the hashmap doesn't contain any values. 
We don't get an error message, so we don't know the problem.
The PK of Artikel is artikelNr and the PK of AangekochtArtikel is a multiple PK namely aankoopNr and artikkelNr.

```
public HashMap<Artikel, Integer> gratisArtikelBepalen(String winkelnaam)
    {
        Database db = new Database();
        Connection con = null;
        Artikel gratisArtikel = new Artikel("",0.0,"",0.0,0.0 ,0, 0.0);
        int aantal = 0;
        HashMap<Artikel, Integer> gratis= new HashMap <Artikel, Integer>();
       int aankoopNr = 0;
       try
       {
           con = db.getConnection();
           Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
           String usql = "SELECT max(aankoopNr) FROM Aankoop WHERE winkelNaam = '" + winkelnaam + "';";
           ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(usql);
           while(rs.next())
            {
              aankoopNr = rs.getInt("max(aankoopNr)");
            }
           String sql = "SELECT Artikel.artikelNr, prijs, aantalBonuspuntenNodig,aantal\n" +"FROM Artikel,AangekochtArtikel\n" +
           "WHERE Artikel.artikelNr = AangekochtArtikel.artikelNr AND aantalbonusPuntenNodig is NOT NULL AND aankoopNr = " + aankoopNr +" AND minBedrag <= bedrag\n ORDER BY prijs DESC;";
           ResultSet re = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
           re.last();
           while(re.next())
           {

            String artikelnr = re.getString("Artikel.artikelNr");
            double prijs = re.getDouble("prijs");
            double aantalBonuspuntenNodig = re.getDouble("aantalBonuspuntenNodig");
            gratisArtikel.setPrijs(prijs);
            gratisArtikel.setAantPuntenNodig(aantalBonuspuntenNodig);
            gratisArtikel.setArtikelNr(artikelnr);
            gratis.put(gratisArtikel, aantal);
           }
          con.close();
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           try { con.close(); } catch(Exception ex2){};
           System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
       }
       return gratis;

    }
```

Comment: Take out those `\n` of your queries it isn't needed.

Comment: And change this: `re.getString("Artikel.artikelNr");` to this: `re.getString("artikelNr");` the recordset doesnt evaluate the table name.

Comment: when you remove \n be sure to replace it with space character or make it \r\n.

Answer (score 0):

try **gratis.Add(gratisArtikel)** or **gratis.Add(gratisArtikel, aantal)**

Or perhaps try to increment aantal variable within the while loop and after

```
gratis.put(gratisArtikel, aantal);
aantal++;
```

It seems that your inserting the new object in index 0